# BigQuery ELT: Reading json lines into federated table as single string column

Tags: google-bigquery

In [this great post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-sql-data-languages-ddl-and-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews), we see a powerful technique to utilize the ELT paradigm of data transformation on newline delimited json files.

However, this post utilizes a hack in the crucial step that creates a
'schemaless' federated table: tell bigquery it's ingesting CSV data with an exotic character as the delimiter and hope the data never contains that delimiter.

I'd like to utilize this approach in a production system without the terrible hack that could lead to bugs (what if our data contains the delimiter?).  Really, all we want to do here is tell bigquery to create a single-column federated table where the single column is a json-formatted string.  Is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: My recommendation for your case, so that you don’t run into bugs when you are reading your data, is to use firestore or datastore to store all the data that you are going to be reading from, so with this you can be sure that your json files are always in a correct format and that your data doesn’t have the delimiter.

Comment: Update: I've created a feature request with Google for this and was told someone is looking into whether to pursue support for this use-case.

Comment: The feature request is currently under review by the product managers and you can track its progress here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205021367

Comment: Will take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think the external table technique is a great way to separate your compute and storage.

It's already handling the decompression, so I don't see any great advantage in *not* asking the BigQuery engine to process the newline delimited JSON format at the same time.

So I would go for something like this (in Bash) and let it autodetect the fields:

```
bq mkdef --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON "gs://your-bucket/your-folder/someprefix*.jsonl" > /tmp/schem.json

bq mk --external_table_definition /tmp/schem.json some_dataset.ext_tab
```

You end up with a table named `ext_tab`, with fieldnames taken from the JSON attributes, that you can query using SQL .. continuing the ELT paradigm.

Comment: Actually though, I don't want BQ to autodetect the schema here.  I want to write up a view that uses the `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY` functions so I can explicitly define my schema at compute time (and flexibly modify at).  Hoffa goes down that route in his post.  The advantage is that if the input json data has an inconsistent schema then I can reconcile it in my view.

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't think I fully understand the benefit of exploding the JSON manually.
As a consumer of semi-structured data you're always at the mercy of the producer when it comes to schema drift.
You may spend a long time carefully building JSON_QUERY functions as per your desired schema, but it's no guarantee that the producer of the JSON puts in the structures that you need?

Comment: Yes Schepo, I agree that we're at the mercy of the data producer; in a way that's the motivation for this approach.  We can write UDFs to flexibly handle cases where the producer creates data in an unexpected schema.